# Retrieve the CAKeyframeAnimationKey's key in AnimationDidStop

Tags: ios, core-animation, key, cakeyframeanimation

I have multiple CAKeyframeAnimation objects, each with a unique key like the following:

```
 .....
 [myAnimation setValues:images];
 [myAnimation setDuration:1];
 ....
 [myLayer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"unique key"];
```

My question is, if I have multiple animation like this and each with a unique key, how do I retrieve their keys in the method AnimationDidStop? I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 -(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation*)animation finished:(BOOL)flag{
 if(..... ==@"uniquekey1"){
 //code to handle this specific animation here:
 }else if(.... ==@"uiquekey2"){
 //code to handle this specific animation here:
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres no public API to retrieve the key.  If you have the layer object you can send it `animationsKeys` to get an array of all its animation keys.  Then you can test each one using `animationForKey:`.

The easiest solution (other than using a separate delegate for each animation) is to create an NSMutableDictionary.  Use the animation object as a key and its animation key string as its value.